# Github action workflow deploy only by specific user

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions

I have a Github workflow to deploy to the production, now in our project production deployment is only triggered by couple of senior/management people.

Now my question, in the Github workflow, how can I only allow only specific people to run production-deploy workflow manually?

Comment: You could inspect `${{ github.actor }}` inside `if` key of a job.